# How to make a list update inside a directive when I update the list in another directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives inside an html.

In the first the user can add "Categories".
In the other directive is where the user can add procedures.

When adding a procedure you have to select to which category it belongs.

When I add one category, the select in procedures should update but it is not updating.

I have to refresh the page to see the updated list.
How can I tell the directive to update the categories select every time I update the categories list?

I'm using the same controller for both directives.

Answer (score 0):

you need a service to share data between directives e.g.

```
app.factory('dataService', [function(){
  return { items: [] };
}]);
```

now your both directives can work on items by accessing this service

```
app.directive('dir1', function(dataService){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h3>Directive 1</h3>' + 
    '<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">' + 
      '<input type="text" ng-model="item.name"/>' + 
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.data = dataService;
    }
  };
});

app.directive('dir2', function(dataService){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h3>Directive 2</h3>' + 
    '<div ng-repeat="item in data.items">' + 
      '<input type="text" ng-model="item.name"/>' + 
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      scope.data = dataService;
    }
  };
});
```

if you share some sample code, i would update above example to suit your need.

Comment: did the answer helped